# .NET client accessing service through service reference error

Tags: .net, wcf

Im trying to access a service through service reference in my .Net client application.
When im accessing the service method, i get the below error:

> Exception caught while accessing the service method
>
> System.Xml.XmlException was caught Message=End element 'Body' from
>   namespace 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/'  expected. Found
>   element 'ns:updateStatusAsReadResponse' from namespace

My app.config looks like this:

```
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
      <binding name="documentproxySoap11Binding" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
             openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
             allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
             maxBufferSize="65536" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536"
             messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered"
             useDefaultWebProxy="true">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
          maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
      <security mode="None">
        <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None"
            realm="" />
        <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
      </security>
    </binding>

  </basicHttpBinding>
  <customBinding>
         <binding name="documentproxySoap12Binding">
      <textMessageEncoding maxReadPoolSize="64" maxWritePoolSize="16"
          messageVersion="Soap12" writeEncoding="utf-8">
        <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
            maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
      </textMessageEncoding>
      <security authenticationMode="MutualCertificate" >
      </security>
      <httpTransport manualAddressing="false" maxBufferPoolSize="524288"
          maxReceivedMessageSize="65536" allowCookies="false" authenticationScheme="Anonymous"
          bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
          keepAliveEnabled="true" maxBufferSize="65536" proxyAuthenticationScheme="Anonymous"
          realm="" transferMode="Buffered" unsafeConnectionNtlmAuthentication="false"
          useDefaultWebProxy="true" />
    </binding>
  </customeBinding>
  <client>
        <endpoint address="http://xxx.documentproxyHttpSoap11Endpoint/"
             binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="documentproxySoap11Binding"
             contract="documentProxy.documentproxyPortType" name="documentproxyHttpSoap11Endpoint" />

  </client>
```

Comment: Can you post the code where your client calls the service, and your client config please?

Comment: My client accesses the service through service reference. so it automatically creates a class. Im using the class method.
DocumentProxy test=new DocumentProxy ();
test.updateStatus();  <-- this is how im accessing the method.

app.config:
<basicHttpBinding>

Comment: <binding name="documentProxySoap11Binding" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
                 openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
                 allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
                 maxBufferSize="65536" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536"
                 messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered"
                 useDefaultWebProxy="true">
 <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"

Comment: maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
          <security mode="None">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None"
                realm="" />
            <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
          </security>
        </binding>
</basicHttpBinding>

Comment: <customBinding> <binding name="documentProxySoap12Binding"> <textMessageEncoding maxReadPoolSize="64" maxWritePoolSize="16" messageVersion="Soap12" writeEncoding="utf-8"> <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384" maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" /> </textMessageEncoding>

Comment: <httpTransport manualAddressing="false" maxBufferPoolSize="524288"
              maxReceivedMessageSize="65536" allowCookies="false" authenticationScheme="Anonymous"
              bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
              keepAliveEnabled="true" maxBufferSize="65536" proxyAuthenticationScheme="Anonymous"
              realm="" transferMode="Buffered" unsafeConnectionNtlmAuthentication="false"
              useDefaultWebProxy="true" />
        </binding>
</customBinding>

Comment: <client>
      <endpoint address="http:/xxxx.documentProxyHttpSoap11Endpoint/"
                 binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="documentProxySoap11Binding"
                 contract="documentProxy.documentProxyPortType" name="documentProxyHttpSoap11Endpoint" />
</client>

Comment: it would be better if rather than post your code and config into multiple comments you just edited your original question to include this.

Comment: @hugh
 I have pasted my config file. 
pls help!

Comment: @hugh :L i have edited the question., pl. have a look at it